# Add main title in visIgraphnetwoork

Tags: r, igraph, visnetwork

goodmoning everyone, I dont manage to add a main title to my visnetwoork obtain with VisIgraph (my graph is a igraph first).

I try to use visSetitle using a dhiny but no that not working.

here is the sipliest exemple to work . could you help please ?

```
library("igraph", quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE, verbose = FALSE)
igraph_network <- graph.famous("Walther")

plot(igraph_network)
visIgraph(igraph_network)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Vislegend() on vis title to do that

> visLegend(main = main_title,position = "left",zoom = FALSE)